# MySQL index key

Tags: mysql, indexing

I've been doing a little research on the MySQL index key for possible database query performance. I have a specific question that hasn't really been answered.

Can you index every field in a table? Or should you just stick to indexing fields that will be in your `WHERE` clause?

Thanks, sorry if this question has been answered before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> A database index is a data structure that improves the speed of data
>   retrieval operations on a database table at the cost of additional
>   writes and storage space to maintain the index data structure. Indexes
>   are used to quickly locate data without having to search every row in
>   a database table every time a database table is accessed. Indexes can
>   be created using one or more columns of a database table, providing
>   the basis for both rapid random lookups and efficient access of
>   ordered records.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_index

You should not create `INDEX` on every fields of table. Use only column which is used for search purpose (i.e `WHERE`, `JOIN`).

Note: Index helps to `SEARCH` faster on table on other hand it has to perform additional `INSERT`, `DELETE` and `UPDATE` so it increase the cost of query.

**Consider scenario:** You `3` or `n` queries with `3` or `n` different fields on same table in this case how to choose index?

It depends on how many times you are executing particular query on table. If you are executing 2 queries very rare then don't create index on that two columns. Create index only on column which is used in query that is executing multiple times.

Comment: Quick question regarding this: Say I have a table called `map_tiles` that stores hundreds of thousands of rows of tile data, if not millions. The fields are `id`, `x`, `y`, `city_id`, and `type`. `city_id`, `x`, and `y` will all eventually end up in their own `WHERE` clause in some `SELECT` queries. Would it be best to go ahead and put indexes on all three of these columns? Thanks, hope my question is clear.

Comment: An `INDEX` is sometimes useful for `GROUP BY` and/or `ORDER BY`.  [Here is a cookbook](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql) on how to derive the 'best' index, given a `SELECT`.

Comment: @RickJames Thank you! This resource is perfect. :)